# Ошибка ввода текста в поле username на форме регистрации

Tags: тестирование, функциональное-тестирование, cypress

Коллеги, пишу на **Cypress** функциональный тест формы регистрации https://demo.realworld.io/#/register

```js
cy.visit('https://demo.realworld.io/#/register');
cy.get('input').type('test');
```

Ожидаю, что Cypress должен ввести текст `test` в поле `username`

Однако, в ходе выполнения получаю **ошибку**  в Cypress:

```
cy.type() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 2 elements!
```

Подскажите, в чем причина? Заранее благодарю

Comment: Cypress не знаю, однако ошибка вам говорит, что ваш селектор `cy.get('input')` вернул 2 элемента, а `.type` может работать только с одним. Изменить селектор `cy.get('input')` что бы он возвращал 1 элемент

Comment: Спасибо, да, Вы правы. Осталось найти лучший селектор для поля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что для указанного селектора `input` **Cypress** находит 2 поля ввода. Cypress не умеет вводить текст в несколько полей ввода одновременно, как собственно и обычный пользователь.

Ваш код нужно исправить так:

```js
cy.visit('https://demo.realworld.io/#/register');
cy.get('.auth-page form input[ng-model$=username]').type('test');
```

Comment: Спасибо, пускай находит 2, а что Cypress сделать не может? И почему в вашем коде 2 типа кавычек? Но сам по себе селектор кажется мне не плохим `.auth-page form input[ng-model$=username]`

Comment: Проблема в том, что для указанного селектора input Cypress находит 2 поля ввода. Cypress не умеет вводить текст в несколько полей ввода одновременно, как собственно и обычный пользователь.

Ваш код нужно исправить так:

```cy.visit('https://demo.realworld.io/#/register');
cy.get('.auth-page form input[ng-model$=username]').type('test');```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your search by `cy.get()`. For this, you should use `'input[placeholder="Username"]'` instead `'input'`.

```
cy.visit('https://demo.realworld.io/#/register');
cy.get('input[placeholder="Username"]').type('test');
```

Try this solution.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Можно ответить на русском? А причина на то в чем? И насколько я знаю использовать селекторы с `placeholder` это плохая практика. Что если я переключу язык приложения на другой? Селектор сразу сломается?